# I tried to install Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 on Xamarin Project.But it shows errors

Tags: xamarin.forms

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **Manage Packages** is for **Forms** project , can not install `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` nuget package .(*AppEntryTest is name of my project*)

[image]

You need to open **Manage Packages for Solution** (*Right click solution -> select Manage Nuget Packages for solution..*)

[image]

then can install as follow :

[image]