# Xamarin.Forms android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms app which I had to update from 3.6 to 4.7. Unfortunately, the Android app does not build anymore. Following error occurs:

```
2>  C:\Foo\90\android\src\crc643f46942d9dd1fff9\FormsAppCompatActivity.java:4: error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder
2>  public class FormsAppCompatActivity
2>         ^
2>    class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found
2>C:\Foo\90\android\src\crc643f46942d9dd1fff9\FormsAppCompatActivity.java(4,8): javac.exe error JAVAC0000:  error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder
2>C:\Foo\90\android\src\crc643f46942d9dd1fff9\FormsAppCompatActivity.java(4,8): javac.exe error JAVAC0000: public class FormsAppCompatActivity
2>C:\Foo\90\android\src\crc643f46942d9dd1fff9\FormsAppCompatActivity.java(4,8): javac.exe error JAVAC0000:   class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found
```

I have tried following solutions:

- Updated all NuGet packages to the newest stable versions
- Removed and reinstalled the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package (28.0.0.3)
- Cleaned solution, deleted bin and obj folders and restarted the IDE
- Tried the same and also deleting the C:\Foo and C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin folder
- I have also tried enabling multi-dexing and setting the dev compiler to d8

I am using:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.6.5
- Xamarin.Android uses 9.0 as a target framework version

Does somebody have any hints towards a solution for this issue? An extensive internet search did not lead to any useful results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like updating my project's TargetFramework from netstandard1.6.1 to netstandard2.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

About installing **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package** can refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209173/i-tried-to-install-xamarin-android-support-v4-on-xamarin-project-but-it-shows-er/62210819#62210819) .

When updating Nuget Package , if there are many packages need to be updated , you'd better select **Select all packages** to update them .Becaues of updating them one by one , there is a possible that occurs conflicts when updating part of them .

Such as updating as follow steps :

[image]